# Does an Algorithm need to have an output necessarily?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

So I did a test on Pseudocode/Algorithms.

There was a True/False statement: `An Algorithm must always have an output.`

I put `F` as my Answer, but the teacher marked it incorrectly.

I thought of [Python]:

`x = 100/4`

The above code just defines `x`. Does not output anything. (Can't it be considered an algorithm?)

Another example I thought, was:

`for x in x:
   y = 9999999999^9999999999/9999999`

Something like that ^ could possibly heat the computer and produce warmth for the user, or something like that. Does not exactly output anything.

Comment: The output in the case of `x = 100/4` is the result of `100/4`. The `algorithm` is division. The output in the case of assignment is hazy, because `x` is both an input and output argument. The output is `x`, but with its value changed.

Comment: What you show is not an algorithm but a simple statement. I think that your teacher meant something else. When you design/develop an algorithm, it is ALWAYS for a purpose, meaning doing something that would _show_ outside the algorithm. That would be its output, the effect of the algorithm on the world outside it.

Comment: One could argue the 'ouput' of say sleep(1) is just the time it takes to execute.  So, I guess no, it doesn't need an output.

Comment: "heat the computer and produce warmth for the user" - isn't it a result of your actions? e.g, every action produces a reaction?

Comment: Although this is more on the philosophical side - what about an algorithm which has a _potential_ output in the sense that there is a specified format of the output, but terminates for none of its input instances such that it does not have an _actual_  output?

Comment: If an algorithm doesn't have an output, it is equivalent to the empty program. (There's no way to observe internal computations, so a program that does the computation and discards it is for all intents and purposes equivalent with one that doesn't perform the computations at all.) So, it boils down to the definition of an algorithm. If the empty program is seen as an algorithm, then an algorithm doesn't need to output anything. As for your last sentence: If emitting heat is part of your computational model, then such algorithm does indeed output something.

Comment: `sleep` does something, it postpones whatever needs to happen after it. A piece of code that, due to its input, ends out with no output is a wrongly defined situation. Its returns `NULL` which also means something (e.g. _the received input did not satisfy one or more conditions_).

Comment: I think we're conflating "output" and "outcome" here. An algorithm quite obviously has to have an outcome, in other words mapping its inputs to a set of values, otherwise it has no observable effects. It does not have to produce output in the sense of writing something to a stream, or producing a diagnostic - as it could just as well store it to memory or some other facility.

Comment: Following up on what Michael said, I'd say that an algorithm must change the state of the system.  That's broad enough to include returning a value, saving files, updating databases - or even generating heat, if you want to include heat in the system.

Answer (score 9):

> "An algorithm has one or more outputs, i.e. quantities which have a specified relation to the inputs" (Knuth 1973:5).

[--Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm#cite_note-6)

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty complicated topic, for the simple fact that algorithm is defined intuitively. For example one may argue as well, that anything that can be implemented as a Turing-Machine is an algorithm. But the language of Turing-Machines is recursively-enumerable. Or put differently: a Turing-Machine needn't terminate and thus not produce any output (if we define the output as what stands on the tape after the machines terminates).

On the other hand, your presented algorithms do output something. The point with your algos is that the output is directly stored within a variable (`x` or `y`). An algorithm outputs something when it terminates, or even during the process. But the output doesn't necessarily need to be produced by a `return`-statements or writing to the console.

To summarize this:
An algorithm either terminates and produces an output, which can as well be directly stored in a variable or somewhere else - might even be a side-effect in a `void`-function. An algorithm may not terminate and thus not produce an output though. But I guess that point is quite a bit beyond the point of the question.